# Thread safety of c_str() in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I have created a class, SettingsClass that contains static strings that hold db connection strings to be used by the MySQL C++ connector library (for e.g. hostname, dbname, username, password).

Whenever a function needs to connect to the database, it calls the .c_str() function on these static strings. For example:

```
Class SettingsClass
{
    public:
    static string hostname;
    ...
}SettingsClass;
string SettingsClass::hostname;

//A function that needs to connect to the DB uses:
driver = get_griver_instance();
driver->connect(SettingsClass.hostname.c_str(),...);
```

The static strings are populated once in the process lifetime. Its value is read from a configuration file.

My application is multithreaded. Am I using c_str() in a safe way?

Comment: Should that be `driver->connect(SettingsClass.hostname.c_str(),...)`?

Comment: Is the SettingsClass populated before the threads are started?

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes, SettingsClass is populated before the threads are started. The application reads these and sets these values from a configuration file before spawning up the threads. Also, it would be c_str(), made the edits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The c_str() in itself should be threadsafe. However, if you have another thread that accesses (writes to) the string that you are taking c_str() of, then you're playing with matches sitting in a pool of petrol.

Typically c_str() is implemented by adding a zero value (the null character 0x00, not the character for zero which is 0x30) on the end of the existing string (if there isn't one there already) and passes back the address of where the string is stored.

Anyone interested can read the libstdc++ code here: 
[libstdc++, basic_string.h](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2b%2b-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h;h=1e3426680fc1facfa136cc135915dee6e85d6a6f;hb=b1fe281557bc7b61f29c140e07364d072a3f2ea6)
The interesting lines are 1802 and 294 - 1802 is the c_str() function, and 294 is the function that c_str() calls.

Comment: The second paragraph is misleading. This is not what `c_str()` is doing. In between being a `const` member and the requirement to return in constant time `O(1)` there is not much leeway to exercise any conditional modifications.

Comment: Ok, I have updated that paragraph to say "typically" that's what it does.

Comment: And that is still wrong for the reasons I outlined. This is **not** what `c_str()` does, nor do I know of **any** implementation that would do that.

Comment: @Tim: The `c_str()` member function can certainly add a null terminator! Just because the string us ligically `const` doesn't mean its internal stirage is `const`, too. ... and adding a null character is certainly an `O(1)` operation.

Comment: @Dietmar C++ does not have a way to model transitive `const`ness. This is a shortcoming of the language. You are correct that adding a `NUL` character is an `O(1)` operation. However, this is **not** what implementations _typically_ do. And since SO is supposed to be a quality service so should be the answers/comments, hence my suggestion to change the paragraph in question.

Comment: libstdc++ definitely DOES just return apointer to the internal data itself (without even adding a zero in c_str(). (Line 1802 in basic_string.h does `return _M_data();`, which is declared on line 294 as `return _M_dataplus._M_p;` - I didn't dig further than that, but to me that's "not copying or processing the string at all". There may be other C libraries that do more complex stuff.

Comment: Added link to libstdc++ in the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

In theoretically at least, the standard allows implementations
which wouldn't be thread safe.  In practice, I don't think
you'll run any risk (although formally, there could be undefined
behavior), but if you want to be sure, just call `.c_str()` once
on all of the strings during initialization (before threads have
been started).  The standard guarantees the validity of the
returned pointer until the next non-const function is called
(even if you don't keep a copy of it), which means that the
implementation cannot mutate any data.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `string` type is constant (so, assume, it is immutable), it is never modified. Any function only reading it should be thread-safe.

So, I think `.c_str()` is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

As long the `std::string` variables are initialized correctly before your threads are started and aren't changed afterwards using the `const char*` representation via `c_str()` should be thread safe.